# App indicator for software RAID running degraded?

Tags: software-recommendation, indicator, raid

Anybody know of a Unity indicator that will indicate if any of my software RAID arrays are running in degraded mode?

Really would be awesome...

Answer (score 0):

Nope, make one :)
It sounds easy but once you get pass RAID 1 it gets complicated, fast.

Comment: FWIW - I am only looking for a RAID 1 solution.

Comment: The problem with writing software like this is the burden of managing the endless tide of demands. I could write a trivial version of this indicator, and I would, if I knew it would stop there. /block/mdx/md/degraded reads 1 if degraded, 0 otherwise. The problem lies in one can easily duplicate the existing md raid management frameworks here, and for what? The majority of use here is server, where folks setup email alerts for when their array is degraded.
http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/application-indicators/
Pretty easy to read a file and change an icon with python. GL!