# Cron script to detect degraded raid array?

Tags: 11.04, raid, cron, system-tray

To my surprise, my raid array entered degraded mode some time ago.  How can I set up a cron job to warn me?   I've tried from the mdadm man page:

```
Running
mdadm --monitor --scan -1
from a cron script will ensure regular notification of any degraded arrays.
```

But on my array this does nothing, despite the problem:

```
# cat /sys/block/md0/md/degraded 
1
# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1]
[raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid1 sdc1[0]
      976759672 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
```

See also:
[App indicator for software RAID running degraded?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165258/app-indicator-for-software-raid-running-degraded)

Comment: I haven't checked if this has changed recently, but last I looked, you did get mail, but not a notification that you got mail. See [Automatic Notification of Degraded RAID Array in Ubuntu](http://superuser.com/questions/175686/automatic-notification-of-degraded-raid-array-in-ubuntu) and then [How are administrators supposed to read root's mail?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2261/how-are-administrators-supposed-to-read-roots-mail)

Comment: @Gilles, you should put that in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu does in fact have this cron job already (check `/etc/cron.daily/mdadm`). Ubuntu also installs [anacron](http://packages.ubuntu.com/anacron) by default, so the job will be run once a day even if you shut down your computer at night.

When a cron job produces output, it is sent to the local mailbox of the user running the crontab (here, the system administrator account, `root`).

Unfortunately, Ubuntu does not set anything up for users to receive and read local mail. So you need to do several things:

- Make sure your machine runs a [mail transfer agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent) such as [postfix](http://packages.ubuntu.com/postfix).
- Have root's mail forwarded to your account. All the system cron jobs run as root. With postfix, edit the file `/etc/aliases` and add a line like

  ```
  root: bryce
  ```

  to forward root's mail to your local mail account.
- If you want your local email to be forwarded to an online account, create a file called `.forward` in your home directory containing your address, e.g. with the command

  ```
  echo bryce@mail-provider.example.com >~/.forward
  ```
- If you want to read your local mail, set up your mail reader program for that.

See [How are administrators supposed to read root's mail?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2261/how-are-administrators-supposed-to-read-roots-mail) for more detailed and up-to-date instructions on reading local administrator mail.